# preservation of extreme points under a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, projection

Suppose we are given a simplex  $X=\{ (x_1,x_2)\in R^2: x_1,x_2\geq 0, x_1+x_2\leq 1\}$ with the extreme points $(1,0)$,$(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$

Consider the product set of $2$-copies of $X$, $X^1\times X^2$. We define a "sum" operation $ T:(x^1,x^2)\to y\in R^4$ by: for every $(x^1,x^2)\in X^1\times X^2$,

$y_{11}=x_1^1+x_1^2$

$y_{12}=x_1^1+x_2^2$

$y_{21}=x_2^1+x_1^2$

$y_{22}=x_2^1+x_2^2$

Denote $Y$ the set of all $y$ given this operation.

If we go over all pairs of extreme points in $X_1$ and $X_2$, we obtain

$Y^*=\{(2,1,1,0),  (1,2,0,1),(1,1,0,0),(1,0,2,1),(0,1,1,2),(0,0,1,1),(1,0,1,0),(0,1,0,1),(0,0,0,0
)\}$

It seems to me that $ Y^*$ always contains all extreme points of $Y$ (since $Y$ is obtained by a projection of $X^1\times X^2$). Moreover, it can be verified that every point in $Y^*$ is an extreme point of $Y$, which seems unusual as $T$ is not invertible.

My question is that why this would be the case and could this result generalize to $K$-copies $X^1\times...\times X^{K} $?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this question for the specific simplex $X$ you gave or for any simplex in general?

Comment: Hi, I mean for the specific simplex $ X$.

Comment: How does the operation $T$ look like for $K>2$ copies of $X$?  Will it be all combinations of the first and second coordinate of $x^1,x^2,x^3$? So we have an operation to $R^8$?

Comment: Yes, we have all combinations of the first and second coordinate of $x^1$,$x^2$,$x^3$ and $y=(y_{ijk})$ in $R^8$.